# Configure TLS connection with AFNetworking 3.x. Custom root CA certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking

I'm trying to connect to my server which have custom CA root certificate.
I can connect to server with code in my custom AFURLSessionManager

```
NSSet *certificatesSet = [CryptoProCSP sharedInstance].certsContextSet;

AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey withPinnedCertificates:certificatesSet];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true;
securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = false;

self.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
```

but getting error

```
[] nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9801]
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
[Error] POST '(null)' (0) [0.8155 s]: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200
"An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
```

I'm already changed my plist.info

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>domain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>1.2</string>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

and server have TLS v1.2

I know problem is different cipher suites, i saw handshake, but how can i customise my request for using necessary cipher suites? I'm sending certificate, but thats not enough. TLS connection failed because of different cipher suites.